# How do I ignore Windows Scaling in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, scaling

I am currently trying to make my JavaFX application compatible with different monitor sizes. When adjusting the Scaling in Windows it doesn't scale my application correctly. With 125% Scaling it seems to only make text bigger, so it doesn't always fit in the containter (Label, Button, etc.). With 150% and larger it seems to scale everything correctly, but the window becomes bigger than the screen, so it isn't really usable.

I've tried `System.setProperty("prism.allowhidpi", "false");` and `System.setProperty("glass.win.uiScale", "100%");` but this doesn't seem to work for me.

Is there an other way to make the application keep its original size?

Comment: smells like a xy-problem: I would suspect something wrong in your layout code. Whatever it is, freezing the scaling is most probably not a solution - so same procedure as always: [mcve] please ;)